# Directory Listing Denied - FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

[I have a website template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/agency/) that I uploaded to my ftp server using FileZilla. However when I visit the domain I get the error:

> **Directory Listing Denied**
>
> This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

in the console it displays a 403 forbidden error. After researching I recognize that the default web page inside the root directory is not set. All my attempts to set the default page have failed. Here is what I tried:

1) Logged into ftp server with FileZilla. Clicked File > Site Manager > Advanced and set the root directory. The root directory contains a file that says index.html

2) Created a .htaccess file in the root that contains the text "DirectoryIndex index.html"

Solutions involving IIS are welcomed as well.

Any advice on how I can get this fixed?

Comment: When `AllowOverride` is set to `None`, `.htaccess` will be completely ignored.

Comment: Where do I go in FileZilla to change AllowOverride?

Comment: If you are running an `apache` server, the file you want to update is either `http.conf` or under the sub directory `conf.d/` create a file that will set it. You don't really need to have `DirectoryIndex` if you want to have the directory listing. You need `mod_autoindex` loaded and set `Options +Indexes`.

Comment: I am fairly certain the server is apache. However there is no http.conf or conf.d/ file available. There are two directories on the server one for my site code and the other is asp-net directory which contains two empty folders

Comment: The directories you are looking at is the website directory, not the server configuration directory. In RHEL or derivatives, the server configuration root directory is located in `/etc/httpd`. In Ubuntu it is in `/etc/apache2`.

Comment: Got it. I'm downloading Ubuntu now. It will complete in 25 min

Comment: Bad news :( I do not have enough space on my hard drive for another OS. The good news is I now have IIS!

Comment: Here's all you need https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Awesome. I will let you know if this works. If it does the bounty is yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not have permissions to access the actual server files so I contacted the hosting company.

They resolved my issue I believe using the approach @alvits recommended, however they have not returned my request to confirm how they solved it.

Thanks for the support